# Insert String into Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, ag-grid

I have a hibernate query that I want to export to an Ag-Grid data javascript file.

I assumed that my variable "persons" was already in a form that Ag-Grid would be able to take and insert the data into the table.  I currently am getting nothing in the table.

I can post the config file for hibernate and Ag-Grid Table constructor file if that would be helpful.

Thank you for your help.

Search hibernate Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class SearchServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SearchServlet")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SearchServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Tbphonebook.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String firstName = request.getParameter("searchFirstName");
        // String lastName = request.getParameter("searchLastName");

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Tbphonebook where firstname = ?");

        query.setParameter(0, firstName);


        List<Tbphonebook> persons = (List<Tbphonebook>) query.getResultList();

        request.setAttribute("persons", persons);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("data.js");

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();        
    }
}
```

Data java script file

```
var ROW_DATA = [{
    persons
}];

function createRowData() {
    return ROW_DATA;
}
```

Index jsp file

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<h1>Search for Contact in Phone Book</h1>
<body>
  <form name="searchInfo" method="get" action="SearchServlet">
        Search First Name: <input type="text" name="searchFirstName"/> <br/>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="action" value="search" />
        
        </form>
</body>


<head>
<style> html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; } </style>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@15.0.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<style>
    button:disabled { color: #a0a0a0; }
</style>

<div style="width: 900px;">
    <div style="padding: 4px">
        <div style="float: right;">
            <input type="text" id="quickFilterInput" placeholder="Type text to filter..."/>
            
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 4px;">
            <b>Phone Book Results</b> <span id="rowCount"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
        id="bestHtml5Grid"
        class="ag-theme-fresh ag-basic">
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried logging what persons looks like?

Comment: I get 

[Tbphonebook [id=20, firstname=Test, lastname=Test, areacode=111, phonenumber=1111111], Tbphonebook [id=...]]

Comment: I have now modified the String toString command so when the persons variable is printed it prints in the exact form Ag-Grid uses [{"firstname" : "test", "lastname" : "test", "areacode" : 111, "phonenumber" : 2222222}]

Thank you Jarod Moser that was probably part of the issue.  Still not getting the data to show up but it now changed from Loading to Now Rows To Show.

Is this the kind of thing where since I now know that that was part of the issue I should edit the original post to show the String toString constructor and all the other hibernate declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this answer breaks the conventional way of programming in jsp since it mixes java script in the jsp file, but it works.

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add contact to Phone Book</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="submitInfo" method="get" action="AddEntryServlet">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/> <br/>
        <br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/> <br/>
        <br/>
        Area Code: <input type="number" name="areaCode"/> <br/>
        <br/>
        Phone Number: <input type="number" name="phoneNumber"/> <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>



<h1>Search for Contact in Phone Book</h1>
<body>

<%Object persons = request.getAttribute("persons"); %>

<br>
  <form name="searchInfo" method="get" action="SearchServlet">
        Search First Name: <input type="text" name="searchFirstName"/> <br/>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="action" value="search" />

        </form>
</body>


</body>

<html>
<head>
<style> html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; } </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@15.0.0/dist/ag-grid.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="quickFilterInput" placeholder="Type text to filter..."/>
<div id="myGrid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-fresh"></div>

    <script>

            var columnDefs = [
                {headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstname'},
                {headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastname'},
                {headerName: 'Area Code', field: 'areacode'},
                {headerName: 'Phone Number', field: 'phonenumber'}
            ]


var persons2 ='<%= persons%>';


var persons3 = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + persons2 + ")"));

var persons4 = JSON.parse(persons3);

var rowData = persons4;


var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        enableRangeSelection: true,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        animateRows: true,

        debug: true,
    onGridReady: function (params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};
 addQuickFilterListener();
 function addQuickFilterListener() {
        var eInput = document.querySelector('#quickFilterInput');
        eInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
            var text = eInput.value;
            gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(text);
        });
    }

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});

    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

The key to the answer is the

```
var persons2 ='<%= persons%>';   
var persons3 = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + persons2 + ")"));
var persons4 = JSON.parse(persons3);
var rowData = persons4;
```

persons2 makes the variable usable by javascript inside the jsp.
persons3 and persons4 make it so the information is able to be used by Ag-Grid

I also made a few changes to the searchServlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;




/**
 * Servlet implementation class SearchServlet
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@WebServlet("/SearchServlet")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SearchServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Tbphonebook.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String firstName = request.getParameter("searchFirstName");


        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Tbphonebook where firstname = ?");

        query.setParameter(0, firstName);


        List<Tbphonebook> persons = (List<Tbphonebook>) query.getResultList();

        request.setAttribute("persons", persons);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();        
    }
}
```

Since all of the java script work is done in index.jsp the data.js file is no longer being used.  This is something that breaks suggested practice but works.